# Skype Chat History in local database file?

Tags: database, windows, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Where can I find chat history of Skype for business in my local machine for getting all messages sent from current system?
Current operating system is Microsoft Windows 10

Comment: Run sysinternals process explorer, View / Lower Pane View / Handles, click on skype processes, and you’ll see a list of currently opened files. Very likely, you’ll find the database among them.
E.g. my skype for desktop keeps multiple different databases in "%appdata%\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop", sqlite and leveldb.

Comment: I am looking for Skype for business database file. I already looked on above path but there is no db file.

Comment: That was just an example.
Run sysinternals process explorer, View / Lower Pane View / Handles, click on skype processes, and you’ll see a list of currently opened files.

Comment: Thanks soonth, through the above process I got one file called SCT_Offline_Storage_Lync_0.dat but I am not able to get data from this .dat extension file, any help:)

Comment: @Soonts Process Explorer opened a complete new world to me and it partly changed my opinion on Microsoft.. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: I found the log files for standard Skype (Windows 10 App) in `%AppData%/Local/Packages/Microsoft.SkypeApp\_<gibberish>_/LocalState/<gibberish>_<skypeusername>.db`; yet I couldn´t extract any useful data from around there. Monitor https://stackoverflow.com/q/53512673/6442316 for updates. You´re also welome to provide any additional info you have some.