# no more local Skype Logs?

Tags: logging, skype

Had quite an oddyssey tracking down the current location of the Skype data (found it in `%AppData%/Local/Packages/Microsoft.SkypeApp\_<somehashcode>_/LocalState/<somegibberish>_<myskypeusername>.db`).

A little more research to find out that it´s a SQLite database; installed [SQLite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/); found all my contacts but no actual chat log. Tried other files in the subdirectory `LocalState/DataRv` without any satisfying results.

Well, I wouldn´t wonder if there were no more local log files at all; but I gave it another shot:

Installed [Skyperious](http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/); took a while to launch ... and it can´t find any data in the loaded file.
Alright ... the latest version of that program is over three years old. Microsoft seems busy ofuscating my data.

I now have spent three hours on trying to find out how to read my own personal logs without the annoying behaviour Skype itself shows when I scroll back in time; might have been faster to just scroll back two years (takes me a minute or so per day; but I guess I have no choice ... see you in 12 hours). I´m wasted.

HELP!

Answer (score 1):

**Skype UWP application Update:**

1. *skype.db* is now using instead *main.db*
2. db tables has changed now.

   [image]

You can now see your chat history under **corelib_messages** (updated)

> **Note:** *Skyperious is using old tables so thats why it shows empty window on chat screen.*

Comment: According to "DB Browser for SQLite", both `LocalState/<myskypeusername>/skype.db` (950KB) and `LocalState/<myskypeusername>/main.db` (270KB) contain (almost) no data. The tables are all empty; however: the views in `skype.db` have content. Might be a bug in the browser ... _SQLiteManager_ from SQLabs also claims that **corelib_messages** is empty (as is **corelib_conversations**); but some other tables (e.g. **contacts** and **conversations**) contain data. Possibly worth noticing: **AppSchemaVersion** contains _Client Version_ 9; _SQLiteSchemaVersion_ 647, _SchemaUpdateType_ 2.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Skype Logs are only available via Download:

- Browse to https://secure.skype.com/en/data-export
- if you want to log in using your password, you may have to chose "other ways to login" and another link to "login using password"
- when logged in, check either or both "Conversations" and "Files"
- and click "Submit Request"
- You´ll get a graybox "Your export is being prepared", and (probably depending on the size of the log and busy-ness of the server) wait a while. I am not sure wether you can just leave the page open or have to refresh; but eventually, a download link will appear.

Conversation Logs are delivered as a json file which is best viewed using the [Skype Parser](https://go.skype.com/skype-parser).